# Undefined Method for send_keys with a valid Capybara element

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, site-prism

I'm trying to call `.send_keys` on a Capybara element I retrieved using a siteprism page model.

Relevant section of page model:

```
class SearchPage < SitePrism::Page
  element :omnisearch_input, "input.db-search__input"
```

In the rails console I can run:

```
@search_page.omnisearch_input

# And then I get:
<Capybara::Element tag="input" path="//HTML[1]/BODY[1]/DIV[1]/SECTION[1]/SECTION[1]/DIV[1]/INPUT[1]">
```

Which to me means I've got a Capybara element, which is exactly what the documentation says I can call `.send_keys` on.  But when I run:

```
@search_page.omnisearch_input.send_keys "some text"
# Result:
NoMethodError: undefined method `send_keys' for #<Capybara::Node::Element:0x007f9effbaaef0>
```

To further enforce this I can call `.set "some text"` on the same element without any trouble. What am I missing?

Comment: What version of Capybara are you using? and what driver/version are you using?

Comment: capybara version 2.4.4, and the driver is poltergeist 1.8.1 with phantomjs 1.9.8.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Capybara 2.4.4 is 2.5 years old, and `send_keys` was added to Element in 2.5.0 - https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara/blob/master/History.md#version-250

You need to update all of the mentioned gems.